# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception Where: Script 'C:\scr\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1256

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

Hello fellow Flutter developers,

I am currently facing a problem with building my Flutter app and I desperately need your help. The error message I am receiving is: **"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception * Where: Script 'C:\scr\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1256 * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'. > Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"**

I encountered this problem when I executed the command "flutter build apk" after running my app on a real Android device. I have tried to solve this issue but I am unable to do so. If any of you have faced this problem before or have any suggestions, please let me know. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

**"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception * Where: Script 'C:\scr\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1256 * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'. > Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"**[image: screen shot]

Comment: Do flutter clean then do flutter pub get then debug and run

Answer (score 0):

**After launching my app on a physical device, I saw the same issue. If the compilation SDK version is less than the actual device's version, this can occur. The following is the fix for the error message, which is not simply restricted to operating on physical devices.**

**Go to:**

> android/app/build.grade

**Change the compileSdkVersion**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
```

Comment: This does not work, it generates another error